# Why the NUnit test cases are passed in locally(Visual Studio) not in Power shell?

Tags: c#, powershell, continuous-integration, nunit, cakebuild

I have a `C# library project and a test project`. The test cases are written using the NUnit.

While I am running the test cases in the `visual studio using the NUnit runner` it passes. My project has a CI automation and **while I am running the same test cases using the PowerShell some of the cases are failing**.

The failed test cases are using the remote machine database connections.

I have no idea on how to proceed further and please share your suggestions.

My Code Block:

```
        [TestCase("SELECT SUM(CAST(`orders`.`OrderID` AS decimal(65,0))) AS `Grid_Column_1` FROM `orders` AS `orders`;", TestName = "GetQueryToSelectRecordsByListOfSchema_MySql_TOTAL()_ReturnsEqual")]
        [Category("ExpressionforMySqlTests")]
        public void GetQueryToSelectRecordsByListOfSchema_DragandDrop_Aggregation_Expression_ReturnsEqual(string _query)
        {
            connectionString = “Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=172.XX.XX.XX9;Port=3306;uid=XXXX;Pwd=XXXXX;Database=northwind; MULTI_STATEMENTS=67108864;”;                            
            var ResultTable = _mySqlQueryBuilder.ExecuteReaderQuery(_query, null, connectionString, ConnectionProviderType.Odbc);
            Assert.IsNotNull(ResultTable, "Expected Result should not be Null");
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried running the tests with PowerShell on the same machine where you use VS Nunit runner?  What's difference between the environment of your workstation and the CI machine?  For example, do you need to install the MySQL ODBC driver, what about environment variables, can the CI machine access the database, etc.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for your comment. I have tested in both PowerShell and VS in my machine. but it is failed only in PowerShell.

Comment: @Jake Yes, the both machine(My Local and CI Machine) have the ODBC driver and it can be access the data base.